# Simulate Taps on a Webpage Swift

Tags: ios, swift, safari, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` that is on the google home page (google.com) and I will like to programmatically select and type 'Apple' inside the google search field and press the 'Google Search' button to look for websites that match 'Apple'.

I was only able to figure out how to interact with simple elements such as the background color (with this https://www.capitalone.com/tech/software-engineering/javascript-manipulation-on-ios-using-webkit). But unfortunately all of the other websites I find are not helpful. How can I do this?